# Array ( [0] => Array ... problems extracting array values

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to run a function that gets information from a DB and returns an array of the values, so I can then extract it on the page.

Inside the function, after my query I have the following code:

```
$example_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) {
    $example_array[] = $row;
}
return $example_array;
```

And there ends my function. Outside of it, I have this:

```
extract($example_array);
```

And I would assume I could then directly `echo` any of the variables that were previously in `$example_array`, e.g. `<?= $example_var ?>` but they do not contain any data.

Running `print_r($example_array);` gives an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [example_var] => Example String ) )
```

The start of that code makes me think my array is somehow "lost" inside another array's first (`[0]`) value, and as such is not extracting correctly.

Have I gone about adding data to that initial `$example_array` incorrectly?

Comment: What does your `$extract` look like?

Comment: Small typo in question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `$example_array[] = $row;`, you assign the current row to a new index of `$example_array`. If you want to access it like `$example_array['row_name']`, you'd have to assign it like this:

```
$example_array = $row;
```

But when you do this, `$example_array` will be overwritten until it has reached the last row (which means that `$example_array` will always contain the last row from the query). If you just want the first row, you can do this and skip the whole `while` loop:

```
$example_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @mpdc now I think of it, it'd be much easier to just do `$example_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);`, which'll get the first row and store it in `$example_array`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `mysql_fetch_array` would have meant `$row['row_name']` was valid.

As you added $row to the array $example_array, you now need to access it via it's array id too, such as;

`$example_array[0]['row_name'], $example_array[1]['row_name']` etc.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? May be easier to offer assistance if we know.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe :

```
$example_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) {
    array_push($example_array, $row['exemple_var']);
}
return $example_array;
```

Comment: PHP doesn't work like most languages, if you do `$array[]` it'll have the same result as `array.push()` in a lot of other languages